NVIDIA 470 DKMS module fails to build on Ubuntu 24.10 Oracular Oriole
I noticed I have no NVIDIA driver loaded after the upgrade to Ubuntu 24.10 (lsmod doesn't list anything like nvidia). At first I thought it's because I was automatically logged in to Wayland that I always have problems with, but logging in to X11 didn't help the issue. Ubuntu now only recognizes my Intel Integrated Graphics. I found the DKMS make log (/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/470.256.02/build/make.log), which has lots of errors, e.g.:
/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/470.256.02/build/common/inc/nv-linux.h: In function ‘nv_phys_to_dma’:
/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/470.256.02/build/common/inc/nv-linux.h:703:12: error: implicit declaration of function ‘phys_to_dma’; did you mean ‘nv_phys_to_dma’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  703 |     return phys_to_dma(dev, pa);
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~
      |            nv_phys_to_dma

At this point, I wondered what version of NVIDIA 470 does 24.10 ship. But apt policy revealed it's basically a dangling package which is not shipped by any repositories.
nvidia-dkms-470:
  Installed: 470.256.02-0ubuntu0.24.04.1
  Candidate: 470.256.02-0ubuntu0.24.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 470.256.02-0ubuntu0.24.04.1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

The packages.ubuntu.com website confirms there is no nvidia-dkms-470 package for Ubuntu 24.10... As far as I know, only the 470 driver is good for my NVIDIA graphics card. How I may install it on my system now?
Here's the lshw report of my video devices:
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GK106GLM [Quadro K2100M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:b0000000-b0ffffff memory:80000000-8fffffff memory:90000000-91ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:b1080000-b10fffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 resolution=2880,1620
       resources: irq:41 memory:b1400000-b17fffff memory:a0000000-afffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff

